# Not able to create 'rmi_keystore.jks' for jmeter distributed testing

Tags: java, linux, bash, ssl, jmeter

I am trying to load test my application using jmeter with remote hosts.

But I am not able to create a 'rmi_keystore.jks' using 'sh create-rmi-keystore.sh' under `/bin` directory of the Jmeter folder.

When I entered the following command it gives the `create-rmi-keystore.sh: 19: keytool: not found`

```
xyz@xyz-HP-EliteBook-840-G2:~$ cd /opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/
xyz@xyz-HP-EliteBook-840-G2:/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin$ sh create-rmi-keystore.sh 
create-rmi-keystore.sh: 19: keytool: not found
Copy the generated rmi_keystore.jks to jmeter/bin folder or reference it in property 'server.rmi.ssl.keystore.file'
xyz@xyz-HP-EliteBook-840-G2:/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin$
```

After reading on the internet i found i have to add the jdk /bin path to the `PATH` var

```
xyz@xyz-HP-EliteBook-840-G2:/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin$ export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_202
xyz@xyz-HP-EliteBook-840-G2:/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin$ export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
xyz@xyz-HP-EliteBook-840-G2:/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin$ echo $PATH
/home/xyz/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/xyz/gaurav/soft/jdk1.8.0_202/bin/bin:/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_202/bin
xyz@xyz-HP-EliteBook-840-G2:/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin$
```

still I am getting `keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (Permission denied)` error

```
xyz@xyz-HP-EliteBook-840-G2:/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin$ sh create-rmi-keystore.sh 
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  rmi
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  A
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  B
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  C
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  D
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  IN
Is CN=rmi, OU=A, O=B, L=C, ST=D, C=IN correct?
  [no]:  yes

Enter key password for <rmi>
    (RETURN if same as keystore password):  
Re-enter new password: 
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (Permission denied)
Copy the generated rmi_keystore.jks to jmeter/bin folder or reference it in property 'server.rmi.ssl.keystore.file'
xyz@xyz-HP-EliteBook-840-G2:/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin$
```

finally tried with `sudo sh create-rmi-keystore.sh` but it gives `create-rmi-keystore.sh: 19: keytool: not found`

```
xyz@xyz-HP-EliteBook-840-G2:/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin$ sudo sh create-rmi-keystore.sh 
[sudo] password for xyz: 
create-rmi-keystore.sh: 19: keytool: not found
Copy the generated rmi_keystore.jks to jmeter/bin folder or reference it in property 'server.rmi.ssl.keystore.file'
xyz@xyz-HP-EliteBook-840-G2:/opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin$
```

I am using **Ubuntu 20.04** and **JMeter 5.4.1**

Please help how can i generate rmi_keystore.jks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create the keystore because your user doesn't have write permissions for the current folder, you can grant your current user ownership for the JMeter folder using [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) like:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/
```

once done you should be able to generate the keystore.

Just in case if you don't want/need secure communication between master and slaves you can add the next line to *user.properties* file

```
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

this way JMeter won't look for the `rmi_keystore.jks` file.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)